# Multiple programs on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: menu, raspberry-pi, multiple-instances, raspberry-pi-zero

I was wondering if you can have multiple programs on a Raspberry Pi Zero W installed and have an overview menu on the Raspberry where you can then choose one of your applications you want to run?

For example you have a program to stream videos from Youtube and Netflix and you have a program you can use for let's say your lighting. And you can go back to your overview menu any time.

I have started programming the streaming app and would like to have multiple apps/programs on one Raspberry I can then use as some sort of Alexa/Homepod.

Oh just to let you know, I would just like to know if it's possible, I am not asking for any kind of code or what so ever, I'm not here for letting someone else do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a docker sistem, in order to run multiple containers on a single machine.
See the following link to start: https://markmcgookin.com/2019/08/04/how-to-install-docker-on-a-raspberry-pi-zero-w-running-raspbian-buster/